# Issue Xampp configuration in Apache with directory Index?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am running Apache 2.2 on Xampp and suddenly starts giving me an error in its starting command prompt saying:

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 248 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command "<DirectoryIndex", perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

..so I check the server configuration in Apache httpd configuration setting in the Xampp Config and change the code:

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`

`<DirectoryIndex> index.php index.html`

```
 # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

`</DirectoryIndex>`

And I have tried closing both the <> and it just keeps saying the same mistake.
Is this a problem with the define command of Directory index ? What is wrong with the comand propmpt do I have to install some extra dependencies??

Comment: You want to use `<Directory /path/to/your/directory/ > Code goes here </Directory>` NOT `DirectoryIndex` NOTE: Don't forget to restart ***XAMPP Web Server***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XAMPP DirectoryIndex Example

For Apache 2.2

```
<Directory /path/to/your/directory/ >  
   DirectoryIndex index.html
 </Directory>
```

#### Example A: Set index.html as an index page, then add index.php to that list as well.

```
<Directory /foo>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

#### Example B: This is identical to example A, except it's done with a single directive.

```
<Directory /foo>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

Restart ***XAMPP Web Server***

Comment: It for sure started working but now It says "Access forbidden
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server." I entered localhost/index.php and https://localhost/index.php and still keeps poppin up. And btw do I keep  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" or delete it since I already have the path in the <directory>?

Comment: @DavidSmirnoff if you defined a oath in your configuration, you must create the path if not exist, otherwise error will occur.  The path in httpd.conf is the default path, the only path that you may change is your machine virtualhost config.  i.e if your web is hosted at ***C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp1, C:/xampp/htdocs/myweb2, C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress*** ...etc, try to use each directory of your webroot in virtualhost.  ***Do not point all webroot to your default htdocs***

Comment: @DavidSmirnoff  >"Access forbidden You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server. is a permission related error.  ***Give xampp permission to read and write to your web directory.***